# Set quantity minimum, maximum and step at product level in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

I'm using "[set minimum and maximum allowable product quantities to be added in WooCommerce Cart](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-set-minimum-and-maximum-allowable-product-quantities-to-be-added-in-woocommerce-cart/)" to require a minimum and maximum quantity order.

Now, i need to impose for several products (not all) a mulitple quantity.
For example : 6 bottles, 12 bottles, 18 bottles (multiple of 6) or for other 12 bottles, 24 bottles (multiple of 12)

I found a solution but it's for every product with a unique value and I cant' manage it in the back office for each product individually.
I have to manage the multiple quantity in Backoffice.

Thank you if you can help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updated** *December 2020*

The following revisited code will allow in addition to handle quantity steps.

I have changed quantity fields settings location to "General" settings tab.

I have added a **checkbox** that enables or disables those additional quantity settings at product level (showing or hiding the setting fields dynamically):

When **checkbox unchecked** *(fields are not visible and quantity settings are disabled)*:

[image]

When **checkbox is checked** *(fields are visible and quantity settings are enabled)*:

[image]

I have merged all settings in a unique custom field as an indexed array of values, to improve performance.

Since WooCommerce version 3, things have changed a lot, so I have made some changes enhancing and updating code to something more newer.

> Also works nicely on Ajax add to cart for simple products, for product variations from variable products and also on the cart quantity input field.

All the code:

```
// Displaying quantity setting fields on admin product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'wc_qty_add_product_field' );
function wc_qty_add_product_field() {
    global $product_object;

    $values = $product_object->get_meta('_qty_args');

    echo '</div><div class="options_group quantity hide_if_grouped">
    <style>div.qty-args.hidden { display:none; }</style>';

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( // Checkbox.
        'id'            => 'qty_args',
        'label'         => __( 'Quantity settings', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'         => empty($values) ? 'no' : 'yes',
        'description'   => __( 'Enable this to show and enable the additional quantity setting fields.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );

    echo '<div class="qty-args hidden">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'                => 'qty_min',
            'type'              => 'number',
            'label'             => __( 'Minimum Quantity', 'woocommerce-max-quantity' ),
            'placeholder'       => '',
            'desc_tip'          => 'true',
            'description'       => __( 'Set a minimum allowed quantity limit (a number greater than 0).', 'woocommerce' ),
            'custom_attributes' => array( 'step'  => 'any', 'min'   => '0'),
            'value'             => isset($values['qty_min']) && $values['qty_min'] > 0 ? (int) $values['qty_min'] : 0,
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'                => 'qty_max',
            'type'              => 'number',
            'label'             => __( 'Maximum Quantity', 'woocommerce-max-quantity' ),
            'placeholder'       => '',
            'desc_tip'          => 'true',
            'description'       => __( 'Set the maximum allowed quantity limit (a number greater than 0). Value "-1" is unlimited', 'woocommerce' ),
            'custom_attributes' => array( 'step'  => 'any', 'min'   => '-1'),
            'value'             => isset($values['qty_max']) && $values['qty_max'] > 0 ? (int) $values['qty_max'] : -1,
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'                => 'qty_step',
            'type'              => 'number',
            'label'             => __( 'Quantity step', 'woocommerce-quantity-step' ),
            'placeholder'       => '',
            'desc_tip'          => 'true',
            'description'       => __( 'Optional. Set quantity step  (a number greater than 0)', 'woocommerce' ),
            'custom_attributes' => array( 'step'  => 'any', 'min'   => '1'),
            'value'             => isset($values['qty_step']) && $values['qty_step'] > 1 ? (int) $values['qty_step'] : 1,
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Show/hide setting fields (admin product pages)
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'product_type_selector_filter_callback' );
function product_type_selector_filter_callback() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( in_array($pagenow, array('post-new.php', 'post.php') ) && $post_type === 'product' ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        if( $('input#qty_args').is(':checked') && $('div.qty-args').hasClass('hidden') ) {
            $('div.qty-args').removeClass('hidden')
        }
        $('input#qty_args').click(function(){
            if( $(this).is(':checked') && $('div.qty-args').hasClass('hidden')) {
                $('div.qty-args').removeClass('hidden');
            } else if( ! $(this).is(':checked') && ! $('div.qty-args').hasClass('hidden')) {
                $('div.qty-args').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Save quantity setting fields values
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'wc_save_product_quantity_settings' );
function wc_save_product_quantity_settings( $product ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['qty_args']) ) {
        $values = $product->get_meta('_qty_args');

        $product->update_meta_data( '_qty_args', array(
            'qty_min' => isset($_POST['qty_min']) && $_POST['qty_min'] > 0 ? (int) wc_clean($_POST['qty_min']) : 0,
            'qty_max' => isset($_POST['qty_max']) && $_POST['qty_max'] > 0 ? (int) wc_clean($_POST['qty_max']) : -1,
            'qty_step' => isset($_POST['qty_step']) && $_POST['qty_step'] > 1 ? (int) wc_clean($_POST['qty_step']) : 1,
        ) );
    } else {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_qty_args', array() );
    }
}

// The quantity settings in action on front end
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'filter_wc_quantity_input_args', 99, 2 );
function filter_wc_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
        $values  = $parent_product->get_meta( '_qty_args' );
    } else {
        $values  = $product->get_meta( '_qty_args' );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $values ) ) {
        // Min value
        if ( isset( $values['qty_min'] ) && $values['qty_min'] > 1 ) {
            $args['min_value'] = $values['qty_min'];

            if( ! is_cart() ) {
                $args['input_value'] = $values['qty_min']; // Starting value
            }
        }

        // Max value
        if ( isset( $values['qty_max'] ) && $values['qty_max'] > 0 ) {
            $args['max_value'] = $values['qty_max'];

            if ( $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->backorders_allowed() ) {
                $args['max_value'] = min( $product->get_stock_quantity(), $args['max_value'] );
            }
        }

        // Step value
        if ( isset( $values['qty_step'] ) && $values['qty_step'] > 1 ) {
            $args['step'] = $values['qty_step'];
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

// Ajax add to cart, set "min quantity" as quantity on shop and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    $values  = $product->get_meta( '_qty_args' );

    if ( ! empty( $values ) ) {
        // Min value
        if ( isset( $values['qty_min'] ) && $values['qty_min'] > 1 ) {
            $args['quantity'] = $values['qty_min'];
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

// The quantity settings in action on front end (For variable productsand their variations)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_wc_available_variation_price_html', 10, 3);
function filter_wc_available_variation_price_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $values  = $product->get_meta( '_qty_args' );

    if ( ! empty( $values ) ) {
        if ( isset( $values['qty_min'] ) && $values['qty_min'] > 1 ) {
            $data['min_qty'] = $values['qty_min'];
        }

        if ( isset( $values['qty_max'] ) && $values['qty_max'] > 0 ) {
            $data['max_qty'] = $values['qty_max'];

            if ( $variation->managing_stock() && ! $variation->backorders_allowed() ) {
                $data['max_qty'] = min( $variation->get_stock_quantity(), $data['max_qty'] );
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you. May i delete the other code (set min/max allowable product...)

Comment: Thanks.This indeed a great solution! However, it sets a min/max/quantity step for the entire product. If you had to do it for indivudal variations, how  would you approach it? I think we can use the filter woocommerce_quantity_input_args and check if product is variable and set min max values in args just like you did but how do I set quanity step for that variation?The args doesn't have step index in that array as per the [docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-product-variable.html#source-view.16). Thoughts?

Comment: @AnkitShah Managing quantity arguments at variation level is only possible for min and max quantity, but not for step quantity. Search there is a plugin that might should do that.

Comment: Great! You know what changes for use step quantity in produt page? With this code only works in cart page. I mean, if step quantity is 25. In product page is possible + and - buttons works adding 25 items for one click and not +1 (26)?

Comment: Any idea on why this is not working with WPML translated languages? It seems to work just on main language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only one item no more than quantity add into cart

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'callback_woocommerce_quantity_changes', 10, 2 );
function callback_woocommerce_quantity_changes( $args, $product ) {
  if ( ! is_cart() ) {
      $args['input_value'] = 1; // Start Input value from this value (By default = 1)
      $args['max_value'] = 1; // Max quantity (By default = -1)
      $args['min_value'] = 1; // Min quantity (By default = 0)
      $args['step'] = 1; // Increment/decrement by this value (By default = 1)
  } else {
      // Cart's "min_value" is already 0 and we don't need "input_value"
      $args['max_value'] = 1; // Max quantity (By default = -1)
      $args['step'] = 1; // Increment/decrement by this value (By default = 0)
  }
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'callback_woocommerce_quantity_min_variation', 9999, 3 );
function callback_woocommerce_quantity_min_variation( $args, $product, $variation ) {
   $args['min_qty'] = 1;
   return $args;
}
```