# Enable decimal quantities and stock for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-quantity

I want to change the default quantity from the products, from 1 to 0,1 but I can't seem to figure it out.

I tried the following:

```
function custom_quantity_input_args($args, $product) {
    $args['input_value'] = 0.10;
    $args['min_value'] = 0.10;
    $args['step'] = 0.10;
    $args['pattern'] = '[0-9.]*';
    $args['inputmode'] = 'numeric';

    return $args;
}
```

The problem with this is that modifies the quantity input from cart as well, which isn't what I want.

To be more specific I want the following:

1. when I go to the product page I want to show 0,1;
2. when I go to the cart page I want to show the current quantity;

The solution I mention above shows 0,1 both in product page and in cart page.
I found another solution, but it shows the current quantity both in product and in cart which, again, it's not what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [Decimal quantity step for specific product categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813870/decimal-quantity-step-for-specific-product-categories-in-woocommerce/64814581#64814581) answer code, try the following revisited code:

```php
// Defined quantity arguments
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 9000, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if( ! is_cart() ) {
        $args['input_value'] = 0.1; // Starting value
    }
    $args['min_value']   = 0.1; // Minimum value
    $args['step']        = 0.1; // Quantity steps
    
    return $args;
}

// For Ajax add to cart button (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    $args['quantity'] = 0.1; // Min value

    return $args;
}

// For product variations (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'filter_wc_available_variation_price_html', 10, 3);
function filter_wc_available_variation_price_html( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $data['min_qty'] = 0.1;
        
    return $data;
}

// Enable decimal quantities (in frontend and backend)
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it partially helps. 
It's great that you offered to modify the shop product button quantity, but the issue is the same as before, meaning, when I get to cart page it shows 0,1 instead of the quantity I added the shopper ads to card.

Comment: I have updated the my question, hopefully it's more explicit.