# Set quantity step at product level in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I need to be able to set the minimum amount and increment step for certain products.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943477/set-quantity-minimum-maximum-and-step-at-product-level-in-woocommerce/65242387#65242387) topic where it is written about the same and there is a code that works and actually adds this functionality.
However, I found a problem: even with the option turned off: Enable this to show and enable ...... product cannot be saved or updated. You must activate the option and put in the field max qty a value greater than 0.
If anyone can help with this problem, it even works for me without the maximum amount. I tried to remove some of the code to remove Maximum Quantity, but after my edits it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated [the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946194/3730754)… Try it and tell me if the problem is solved here in this comment zone…

Comment: Hello
Thank you very much for your help and for sharing with us. After your last edit the problem is solved now everything works perfectly.
If I'm not being cheeky, I want to ask if there's a way to get these settings for a group of products?

Comment: Mostly everything is possible… Sorry, but we expected you to provide in your questions your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service. So if you don't know how to do it, you should hire a developer…